# Do raw strings in python disable meta characters such as \w or \d just as they do with \n?

Tags: python, regex

I am new to Python. Can someone tell me what is the difference between these two regex statements (re.findall(r"\d+","i am aged 35")) and (re.findall("\d+","i am aged 35")).

I had the understanding that the raw string in the first statement will make "\d+" inactive because that is the primarily role of a raw string - to make escape characters inactive.  In other words "\d+" will not be a meta character for finding/searching/matching digits if a raw string is used. However, I now see that both statements return the same result.

Comment: Required reading: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague

Answer (score 1):

Both the Python parser *and* the regular expression parser handle escape sequences. This means that any escape sequence that *both engines* support must either use double slashes, or you use a raw string literal so the Python parser doesn't try to interpret escape sequences.

In this case, `\d` has no meaning to *Python*, so the backslash is left in place for the `re` module to handle. So *here specifically*, there is no difference between the two snippets.

However, if you needed to match a *literal backslash* before other text like `section` in your regular expression, without raw strings, you'd have to use `'\\\\section'` to define the pattern! That's because the Python interpreter would see `'\\section'` as an escape sequence producing a single backslash, and then the regular expression parser sees the start of the escape sequence `\s`.

See the [section on backslashes and raw string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague) in the Python regular expression HOWTO.

Comment: Hi There, Thank you. I am still unable to understand why would i need to use '\\\\' to match a literal backslash in a string.

Comment: @PankajKulkarni: `'\section'` is not a valid Python escape, so you get `'\section'` in the regex, which sees `\s`, a metacharacter. `'\\section'` becomes a single `\` in the value, so `'\section'` is passed to the regex engine, which still sees `\s`, a meta-character. Only `'\\\\section'` becomes the value `\\section`, so now the regex engine sees `\\` as a literal backslash separate from the `section` part.